# Laravel One to Many to return names within ids

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a main table called `items`, which has many foreign keys of other tables, like (`categories`, `sections` .. etc.).

I have created a `one-to-many` relationships between other tables towards the `items` table, so each category could be assigned to multiple items and so on for others.

I want to get the `items` table filled with `names` from other tables, not only the ids.

So it should look like that:

```
{id: 1, category_name: first, section_name: x .. }
```

What I get is:

```
{id: 1, category_id: 1, section_id, 1}
```

Can I get the names only from the query? As I want to pass them as JSON to datatables.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can do that if you join items table with other tables. Or just define models for all your tables and you'll be able to use the power of Eloquent to do get all the data easily.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I did define all models, but can't get a row of data with full records from both tables (as JOIN do).

Comment: I have no idea what you'll be doing with this data later, in general models should be your best option, but if you really want to get everything in a single row then the join is your only option - see the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Just want to display specific rows from multiple tables.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo let's say I want to display names instead of ids.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo just updated the question.

Comment: did you use eloquent or query builder?

Comment: @Yachi웃 I used eloquent.

Comment: If you use eloquent. I think you must get foreign key to associate with other tables. But if you want to reduce other outputs like category_slug..., you can do it by setting up the array of columns you want to get in model. (Sorry because of my English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The idea](https://www.classle.net/submission/objectives-normalization) of a normalized database is to avoid duplicating data and to keep integrity among other things.

---

## Option 1: API Resources

Now for your case, if you are trying to use Laravel as a backend, you can use the new feature of the 5.5 version of Laravel called [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources). It helps you to format the output of objects such as models or collections, to display attributes and also relationships.

So, you could do something like this in your `ItemResource` resource:

**App\Http\ResourcesResources\ItemResource.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ItemResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->user_id,
            // To access relationship attributes:
            'category_name' => $this->category->name,
            'section_name' => $this->section->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, you just need to create a new `ItemResource` instance and pass the `Item` object that you want to return:

```php
use App\Http\Resources\ItemResource;

// some code

    /**
     * Show a single formatted resource.
     *
     * @param Item $item
     * @return ItemResource
     */
    public function show($item)
    {
        return new ItemResource($item);
    }

// the rest of your code
```

The output would be the expected.

---

## Option 2: Loading relationships

Other way to do this is to [Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) or [Lazy Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the relationships in your `Item` object, something like this:

```php
// some code

        /**
         * Return a single item object.
         *
         * @param integer $id
         * @return ItemResource
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            $item = Item::find($id);
            $item->load(['category','section','etc']); // all of your relationships

            return $item;
        }

// the rest of your code
```

This will output the `$item` but with nested data, like:

```json
{
    "id":51,
    "name": "Some item name",
    "category": {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "category name"
    }
    "section": {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "section name"
    }
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Then in your view you just access the properties like:
`$item->category->name`

Comment: That's amazing, close enough to what I am looking for, just trying to get over nested ones.

Comment: @CairoCoder that's why I started with option 1. Using API Resources returns the data exactly the way you need it. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gyr5ZMNaPbc&t=840s) for assistance or just go to the documentation (the link is in the response).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options in my mind.

1. Use the join tables. Reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins

For example:

```
$data = DB::table('data')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'data.category_id')
    ->join('sections', 'sections.id', '=', 'data.section_id')
    ->select('data.id', 'categories.name as category_name', 'sections.name as section_name')
    ->get();
```

---

2. Using eloquent relation to the relationship of the model. So you can call, for example `$data->category->name` to call category's name or `$data->section->name` to call section's name. Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many.

If you want to use option no 2 and want to place it into rows, you can use Laravel Collection (map function) (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)

Comment: Can I get them all in rows, as I want to pass them as JSON for datatables.

Comment: It will be much simpler with option no 1, I updated with the example @CairoCoder

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using laravel [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) method like

```html
class Item extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryNameAttribute()
    {   //Your model relation here
        return $this->categories()->first()->category_name;
    }
}
```

and you can do same with the section_name

**Note:**
Use `protected $appends = ['category_name'];` in your item model if you want to get it in JSON

Comment: Will give it a try.